# Simple Multi-Threaded Web Server

Tags: c++, multithreading, http, server, web-services

Need a way to test a web crawler.

Threw together this web server that will replay previously saved pages from a real web server.

### Headers

```
#include <stdexcept>
#include <memory>
#include <map>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cerrno>
#include <strings.h>

#include <pthread.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>



extern "C" void* workerThread(void*);
```

### Multi Threading Stuff

```
class SimpleThread
{
    pthread_t       thread;

    SimpleThread(SimpleThread const&);
    SimpleThread& operator=(SimpleThread const&);

    public:
        SimpleThread()
        {
            if (::pthread_create(&thread, NULL, workerThread, NULL) != 0)
            {
                throw std::runtime_error("Failed to Start Thread");
            }
        }
        ~SimpleThread()
        {
            void*   result;
            if (::pthread_join(thread, &result) != 0)
            {
                throw std::runtime_error("Failed to Join Thread");
            }
        }
};

class SimpleCondition;
class SimpleMutex
{
    SimpleMutex(SimpleMutex const&);
    SimpleMutex operator=(SimpleMutex const&);

    friend class SimpleCondition;
    pthread_mutex_t     mutex;

    public:
        SimpleMutex()
        {
            if (::pthread_mutex_init(&mutex, NULL) != 0)
            {
                throw std::runtime_error("Failed to Create Mutex");
            }
        }
        ~SimpleMutex()
        {
            ::pthread_mutex_destroy(&mutex);
        }
        void lock()
        {
            if (::pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex) != 0)
            {
                throw std::runtime_error("Filed to lock mutex");
            }
        }
        void unlock()
        {
            if (::pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex) != 0)
            {
                throw std::runtime_error("Faile to unlock mutex");
            }
        }
};
class Locker
{
    SimpleMutex&    m;
    public:
        Locker(SimpleMutex& m)
            : m(m)
        {
            m.lock();
        }
        ~Locker()
        {
            m.unlock();
        }
};

class SimpleCondition
{
    SimpleCondition(SimpleCondition const&);
    SimpleCondition operator=(SimpleCondition const&);

    pthread_cond_t cond;
    public:
        SimpleCondition()
        {
            if (::pthread_cond_init(&cond, NULL) != 0)
            {
                throw std::runtime_error("Failed to init condition variable");
            }
        }
        ~SimpleCondition()
        {
            ::pthread_cond_destroy(&cond);
        }
        void wait(SimpleMutex& mutex)
        {
            if (::pthread_cond_wait(&cond, &mutex.mutex) != 0)
            {
                throw std::runtime_error("Failed to wait on mutex");
            }
        }
        void notify()
        {
            if (::pthread_cond_signal(&cond) != 0)
            {
                throw std::runtime_error("Failed to notify");
            }
        }
        void releaseAll()
        {
            if (::pthread_cond_broadcast(&cond) != 0)
            {
                throw std::runtime_error("Failed to release all");
            }
        }
};
```

### Very Simple Job and Queue

```
/* Job object
 *  sockfd:     The stream file descritor to send the reply on.
 *  fileName:   The name of the file with data to be sent.
 */
struct Job
{
    int         sockfd;
    std::string fileName;
    Job*        next;

    Job(int sockfd, std::string const& fileName)
        : sockfd(sockfd)
        , fileName(fileName)
        , next(NULL)
    {}
    ~Job()
    {
        if (sockfd)
        {
            ::close(sockfd);
        }
    }
};

class WorkQueue
{
    Job*            head;
    Job*            tail;
    SimpleMutex     access;
    SimpleCondition condition;
    bool            finished;

    public:
        WorkQueue()
            : head(NULL)
            , tail(NULL)
            , finished(false)
        {}
        ~WorkQueue()
        {
            finished = true;
            condition.releaseAll();
            while(head)
            {
                Job*    item    = head;
                head = item->next;
                delete item;
            }
        }
        void addItem(Job* another)
        {
            {
                Locker      lock(access);
                if (head == NULL)
                {
                    head        = another;
                }
                else
                {
                    tail->next  = another;
                }
                tail        = another;
            }
            condition.notify();
        }
        Job* getItem()
        {
            Locker      lock(access);
            while(head == NULL)
            {
                condition.wait(access);
                if (finished)
                {
                    return NULL;
                }
            }
            Job*        result = head;
            head = result->next;
            if (result == tail)
            {
                tail = NULL;
            }
            return result;
        }
};
```

### The Socket

```
class SimpleSocket
{
    int sockfd;
    public:
        SimpleSocket(int port)
        {
            sockfd = ::socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
            if (sockfd < 0)
            {
                throw std::runtime_error("Failed to create socket");
            }

            struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
            ::bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));

            serv_addr.sin_family        = AF_INET;
            serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr   = INADDR_ANY;
            serv_addr.sin_port          = htons(port);

            if (::bind(sockfd, reinterpret_cast<sockaddr*>(&serv_addr), sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0)
            {
                throw std::runtime_error("Failed to bind to port");
            }
        }
        ~SimpleSocket()
        {
            ::close(sockfd);
        }
        int waitForConnection()
        {
            int result = ::listen(sockfd,5);
            if (result < 0)
            {
                throw std::runtime_error("Listen failed");
            }
            sockaddr_in     cli_addr;
            socklen_t       clilen      = sizeof(cli_addr);
            int             newsockfd   = ::accept(sockfd, reinterpret_cast<sockaddr*>(&cli_addr), &clilen);
            if (newsockfd < 0)
            {
                throw std::runtime_error("accept failed");
            }
            return newsockfd;
        }
};
```

## Class for abstracting Pages

```
/* The set of pages the can be returned */
class Pages
{
    public:
        // Note 1: page contains the server name and page.
        // See:    getPageFromRequest()
        // Note 2: A response is preset in the files <filaName>.head <filaName>.body
        // See:    workerThread()
        Job* getJob(int sockfd, std::string page) const
        {
            std::string  fileName = std::string("/mnt/Pages/") + page;

            struct stat buffer;
            bool ok = ::stat((fileName + ".head").c_str(), &buffer) != 0)
                  &&  ::stat((fileName + ".body").c_str(), &buffer) != 0)
            if (!ok)
            {
                // Note: Invalid will not clash with saved pages.
                //       because pages are in sub-directories based on
                //       the server name.
                return new Job(sockfd, "/mnt/Pages/Invalid");
            }
            return new Job(sockfd, fileName);
        }
};
```

### Helper function for reading/writing to stream

```
/* Copy a buffer to stream */
void sendToClient(int sockfd, char* buffer, int size)
{
    std::size_t write = 0;
    while(write != size)
    {
        std::size_t out = ::write(sockfd, buffer + write, size - write);
        if (out == -1 && (errno == EAGAIN || errno == EWOULDBLOCK || errno == EINTR))
        {
            continue;
        }
        if (out == -1)
        {
            throw std::runtime_error("Failed to write to socket");
        }
        write += out;
    }
}

/* Copy a File to a stream */
void writeFile(int sockfd, std::string const& fileName)
{
    char                buffer[4096];
    std::ifstream       file(fileName.c_str());
    std::size_t         count;

    do
    {
        file.read(buffer, 4096);
        count = file.gcount();
        sendToClient(sockfd, buffer, count);
    }
    while(count > 0);
}
/* Read the request from the socket */
std::string getPageFromRequest(int connection)
{
    char buffer[4097];
    std::size_t read = 0;
    while(true)
    {
        std::size_t atual = ::read(connection, buffer + read, 4096 - read);
        if (atual == 0)
        {
            break;
        }
        if (atual == -1 && (errno == EAGAIN || errno == EINTR))
        {
            continue;
        }
        if (atual == -1)
        {
            throw std::runtime_error("Read Error");
        }
        read += atual;
        if (read == 4096)
        {
            break;
        }
        if ((read > 3) && buffer[read - 3] == '\n' && buffer[read - 2] == '\r' && buffer[read - 1] == '\n')
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    static std::string const marker = "Host: ";

    char* pageSt  = buffer + 4;
    char* pageEnd = std::find(pageSt, buffer + read, ' ');
    char* servSt  = std::search(buffer, buffer + read, marker.begin(), marker.end());
    char* servEnd = std::find(servSt + marker.size(), buffer + read, '\r');

    std::string req = std::string(servSt + marker.size(), servEnd) + std::string(pageSt, pageEnd);
    return std::string(pageSt, pageEnd);
}
```

### The work part of the server

```
WorkQueue       work;
void* workerThread(void*)
{
    Job* job;
    try
    {
        while(job = work.getItem())
        {
            std::auto_ptr<Job>    workItem(job);
            if (job->sockfd)
            {
                writeFile(workItem->sockfd, workItem->fileName + ".head");
                writeFile(workItem->sockfd, workItem->fileName + ".body");
            }
        }
    }
    catch(...){}

    return NULL;
}

int main()
{
    SimpleThread    workers[8];
    SimpleSocket    socket(80);
    Pages           pages;

    int connection;
    while(connection = socket.waitForConnection())
    {
        std::string page = getPageFromRequest(connection);
        work.addItem(pages.getJob(connection, page));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, I really liked your C++ code and even though I am not a professional I think there are some points to consider.

### To the future!

It is 2016 so I would say we can safely use C++11 today (at least if you are not held back by embedded, an ancient compiler, etc.). There being at least three major compilers with C++11 support this shoud not be a problem.

I went through your code from top to bottom and the first thing was `SimpleThread`. It is good but we do not need it because there is std::[thread](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread)

```
int main() {
  std::vector<std::thread> workers{std::thread::hardware_concurrency()};
  ...
  for(auto& worker : workers) {
    worker = std::thread(workerThread, nullptr);
  }
}
```

So instead of using `8` as a safe assumption for our threads I used [hardware_concurrency](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/hardware_concurrency)() to ask the system how many cores it has/we can utilize. The constructor of `thread`is more generic than `SimpleThread` and takes the function as a parameter. `thread` being templated we can safely use a C++ function with arbitrary arguments which allows us to change `workerThread` to

```
void workerThread(WorkQueue& work)
```

and enables us to remove the global variable and the unneccessary `return null` which would be in C++11 terms `return nullptr`. Because we pass a reference we have to use `thread(workerThread, std::ref(work))` to allow the template magic to find the right `workerThread`.

Going forward, your classes `SimpleCondition` and `SimpleMutex` are redundant as well because there are std::[condition_variable](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable) and std::[mutex](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex) which do pretty much the same thing.

Instead of `releaseAll()` and `notify` we use `notify_all()` and `notify_one()` (which describes their use cases and similarity better). To lock the mutex we use `std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock{access}` which works like your `Lock`. A real difference is in `condition.wait()` because it takes the lock and not the mutex as a parameter `condition.wait(lock)`.

I know everyone (in C/C++) likes to implement their linked lists, but why bother when there is no real benefit. It takes more work, it increases cache misses because the objects are scattered in the memory and in your implementation it locks `Job` to this implementation without a reason. `Job` should just be a data structure regardless of the container it is put in. So I removed `Job* next` from it.

To accomodate `WorkQueue` has to change as well. I decided to put a std::[queue](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/queue) in it because it is exactly what we need.

```
class WorkQueue {
  std::queue<std::unique_ptr<Job>> jobs;
  std::mutex access;
  std::condition_variable condition;
  bool finished;

  public:
    WorkQueue()
      : finished(false)
    {}
    ~WorkQueue() {
      finished = true;
      condition.notify_all();
    }
    void addItem(std::unique_ptr<Job> another) {
      {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock{access};
        jobs.push(std::move(another));
      }
      condition.notify_one();
    }
    std::unique_ptr<Job> getItem() {
      std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock{access};
      condition.wait(lock, [this] () { return !jobs.empty() || finished; });
      if (finished) {
        return std::unique_ptr<Job>(nullptr);
      }
      std::unique_ptr<Job> nextJob = std::move(jobs.front());
      jobs.pop();
      return nextJob;
    }
};
```

While I was at it I changed `Job*` to a std::[unique_ptr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr). I saw you used std::auto_ptr, do not use it, it is deprecated and will be removed in C++17. unique_ptr is not copy-constructible/-assignable therefore we have to move it into `jobs` in `addItem` and out of it in `getItem`.

A more drastic change is the wait logic. I could have used `condition.wait(lock)` in a while loop but there is an overload of [wait](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable/wait)() which takes a predicate to check if waiting is over and it fits this perfectly.

In your `getJob` I created the `unique_ptr` using std::[make_uniqe](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/make_unique)() which is the highly recommended way to create `unique_ptr`s. While I was at it I made it static because it removes the need to instantiate `Pages`.

### Destroy all the things!

Wait what?! Even though I wanted to show you all these neat ways which simplify your code in the end I deleted all your thread code and most of my changes because there is a simpler solution to your problem.

You know that IO takes time and blocks so you thought of a way to make it asynchronous. The common approach, as you did, is to implement some kind of threadpool logic with workers and creators. But there is an alternative, std::[async](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async). It encapsulates the asynchronous logic and is required to act like if it was a `std::thread`. Most implementations problably use a threadpool so it is exactly what you did, just less work for you.

I removed `SimpleQueue` and changed `workerThread` (not being a thread anymore)

```
void handleJob(std::unique_ptr<Job> job) {
  if (job->sockfd) {
    writeFile(job->sockfd, job->fileName + ".head");
    writeFile(job->sockfd, job->fileName + ".body");
  }
}

int main() {
  std::vector<std::future<void>> pending_futures;
  SimpleSocket socket(80);

  int connection;
  while(connection = socket.waitForConnection()) {
    std::string page = getPageFromRequest(connection);
    pending_futures.push_back(std::async(std::launch::async, handleJob, Pages::getJob(connection, page)));
  }
}
```

The call to `async` returns a std::[future](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future) which gives a way to retrieve the return value of our operation. Moreover, it enables you to join the operation, if you want that or not. Because the destructor automatically joins the operation if it is not finished we have to keep the `future`s around. One might want to clean these up, but this is left as an exercise for the reader ;)

### Going experimental

Huh C++11/C++14 is not enough? How about the Filesystem TS which will someday (might be C++17) be in the standard. Nevertheless there are implementations in gcc (5.x+ I guess) and VS (2015) (clang says no work started) which you can use with `#include <experimental/filesystem>`.

It has a clean and portable API to work with filesystems, even though I only used it in one place I think it is more descriptive.

```
namespace fs = std::experimental::filesystem;
...
bool ok = fs::is_regular_file(fileName + ".head") && fs::is_regular_file(fileName + ".body");
```

I am not sure if this is what you meant with your `stat` call because you only check for errors. But a nonexistent file does not return an error code. But from the context I think a check with [is_regular_file](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/fs/is_regular_file)() is a reasonable check to make.

Theoretically there is also a Networking TS which should be tested by example implementation in the compilers like the Filesystem TS but I could not find any compiler implementing it. With this TS your network code could be simplified as well, but this is for another day.

### The final code

```
#include <stdexcept>
#include <memory>
#include <map>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <queue>
#include <future>
#include <experimental/filesystem>

#include <cstring> // strerror
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cerrno>
#include <strings.h>

#include <unistd.h> // ::close

#include <netdb.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>

using namespace std::literals;
namespace fs = std::experimental::filesystem;

/* Job object
 *  sockfd:     The stream file descritor to send the reply on.
 *  fileName:   The name of the file with data to be sent.
 */
struct Job
{
    int         sockfd;
    std::string fileName;

    Job(int sockfd, std::string const& fileName)
        : sockfd(sockfd)
        , fileName(fileName)
    {}
    ~Job()
    {
        if (sockfd)
        {
            ::close(sockfd);
        }
    }
};

class SimpleSocket
{
    int sockfd;
    public:
        SimpleSocket(int port)
        {
            sockfd = ::socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
            if (sockfd < 0)
            {
                throw std::runtime_error("Failed to create socket");
            }

            struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
            ::bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));

            serv_addr.sin_family        = AF_INET;
            serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr   = INADDR_ANY;
            serv_addr.sin_port          = htons(port);

            if (::bind(sockfd, reinterpret_cast<sockaddr*>(&serv_addr), sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0)
            {
                throw std::runtime_error("Failed to bind to port: "s + std::strerror(errno));
            }
        }
        ~SimpleSocket()
        {
            ::close(sockfd);
        }
        int waitForConnection()
        {
            int result = ::listen(sockfd,5);
            if (result < 0)
            {
                throw std::runtime_error("Listen failed");
            }
            sockaddr_in     cli_addr;
            socklen_t       clilen      = sizeof(cli_addr);
            int             newsockfd   = ::accept(sockfd, reinterpret_cast<sockaddr*>(&cli_addr), &clilen);
            if (newsockfd < 0)
            {
                throw std::runtime_error("accept failed");
            }
            return newsockfd;
        }
};

/* The set of pages the can be returned */
class Pages
{
    public:
        // Note 1: page contains the server name and page.
        // See:    getPageFromRequest()
        // Note 2: A response is preset in the files <filaName>.head <filaName>.body
        // See:    workerThread()
        static std::unique_ptr<Job> getJob(int sockfd, std::string page)
        {
            std::string  fileName = std::string("./Pages/") + page;

            bool ok = fs::is_regular_file(fileName + ".head") && fs::is_regular_file(fileName + ".body");
            if (!ok)
            {
                // Note: Invalid will not clash with saved pages.
                //       because pages are in sub-directories based on
                //       the server name.
                return std::make_unique<Job>(sockfd, "./Pages/Invalid");
            }
            return std::make_unique<Job>(sockfd, fileName);
        }
};

/* Copy a buffer to stream */
void sendToClient(int sockfd, char* buffer, int size)
{
    std::size_t write = 0;
    while(write != size)
    {
        std::size_t out = ::write(sockfd, buffer + write, size - write);
        if (out == -1 && (errno == EAGAIN || errno == EWOULDBLOCK || errno == EINTR))
        {
            continue;
        }
        if (out == -1)
        {
            throw std::runtime_error("Failed to write to socket");
        }
        write += out;
    }
}

/* Copy a File to a stream */
void writeFile(int sockfd, std::string const& fileName)
{
    char                buffer[4096];
    std::ifstream       file(fileName.c_str());
    std::size_t         count;

    do
    {
        file.read(buffer, 4096);
        count = file.gcount();
        sendToClient(sockfd, buffer, count);
    }
    while(count > 0);
}
/* Read the request from the socket */
std::string getPageFromRequest(int connection)
{
    char buffer[4097];
    std::size_t read = 0;
    while(true)
    {
        std::size_t atual = ::read(connection, buffer + read, 4096 - read);
        if (atual == 0)
        {
            break;
        }
        if (atual == -1 && (errno == EAGAIN || errno == EINTR))
        {
            continue;
        }
        if (atual == -1)
        {
            throw std::runtime_error("Read Error");
        }
        read += atual;
        if (read == 4096)
        {
            break;
        }
    // hackery but for this simple job ¯\(0_0)/¯
        if ((read > 3) && buffer[read - 3] == '\n' && buffer[read - 2] == '\r' && buffer[read - 1] == '\n')
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    static std::string const marker = "Host: ";

    char* pageSt  = buffer + 4;
    char* pageEnd = std::find(pageSt, buffer + read, ' ');
    char* servSt  = std::search(buffer, buffer + read, marker.begin(), marker.end());
    char* servEnd = std::find(servSt + marker.size(), buffer + read, '\r');

    std::string req = std::string(servSt + marker.size(), servEnd) + std::string(pageSt, pageEnd);
    return std::string(pageSt, pageEnd);
}

void handleJob(std::unique_ptr<Job> job) {
    if (job->sockfd)
    {
        writeFile(job->sockfd, job->fileName + ".head");
        writeFile(job->sockfd, job->fileName + ".body");
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::future<void>> pending_futures;
    SimpleSocket    socket(8100);

    int connection;
    while(connection = socket.waitForConnection())
    {
        std::string page = getPageFromRequest(connection);
        std::cout << "serving page " << page << std::endl;
        pending_futures.push_back(std::async(std::launch::async, handleJob, Pages::getJob(connection, page)));
    }

}
```

Comment: Fantastic I loved the review. It was sort of deliberate to use only C++03 features to try and get people to review it to get the C++11 -> C++17 features discussed.

Comment: Normally I would even recommend the use of `std::vector` over `std::list` to hold Jobs in nearly every situation (because of memory locality and caching). But this may (and I emphasis may) be one situation where `std::list` (as you pointed out) is the better alternative.

Comment: `deprecated and will be removed in C++17` Maybe. I'll believe that when I see it. Things stay deprecated rather than removed to maintain backward compatibility. But you may be correct it is relatively easy to move to `std::unique_ptr`

Comment: I had not seen the `Filesystem TS` thank you for that.

Comment: `auto_ptr` and some other things which are superseded by better alternatives are removed by [N4190](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4190.htm) which is adopted according to [Herb Sutter](http://herbsutter.com/2014/11/24/updates-to-my-trip-report/) (secretary of the ISO C++ working group)

Comment: I also love the review! Can you elaborate bit more about async. Why you put those jobs in a vector? and how they get deleted when job is done? I do not see how this happen? Even if async work finishes, I believe, it stay in the vector?

Comment: When the destructor of future is called it will join the async operation, defeating its purpose. Therefore, I store them. As said in the review, I omitted the cleanup of futures which already ran. Basically you loop over the vector and remove all futures which finished.